# Isn't this a contradiction to the zero partial derivative necessary condition for an extremum?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

I learned that for a point to be an extremum of a function, the necessary condition is that the *partial* derivatives of the function with respect to its variables must be zero. However, suppose I have a function
$$f(x,y(x)) = x - \sqrt{y}$$
and $y$ implicitly depends on $x$ such that $y(x) = x$.

The minimum of this function is achieved at $x = 1/4$.

However, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1$ for all $x$.

Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: No. In your expression, $y$ is a function of $x$. The partial derivative is not as simple as $1$.

Comment: @BernardPan I think it is $1$, since it is a *partial* derivative, not total.

Comment: You can substitute $y$ simply by $x$ since $y(x)=x$. Then $f$ would be a univariate function. Besides, if you want to regard $f$ as a bivariate function, you are supposed to apply the chain rule to get the partial derivative.

Comment: @BernardPan I basically copied the example from here (with some modification): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Example:_Differentiation_with_direct_dependencies. They didn't do the substitution when computing the partial derivative.

Comment: Sorry, I made this whole confusing. You do not need to do the substitution while applying the chain rule. The correct way is like this: $f_x=1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: @BernardPan Isn't that the total derivative?

Comment: Nope. Since you want to differentiate $f$ with $x$, you are supposed to differentiate each term of $f$ with $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

> for a point to be an extremum of a function, the necessary condition is that the partial derivatives of the function with respect to its variables must be zero

the variables must be independent.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The partial derivative with respect to $x$ is indeed $1$. Sorry, I made it wrong before.

However, the main difference here is that we have a restriction on $y$. Globally $x=1/4$ is not an extremum or there is even no global extremum for $f$, because $f_x=1$ is a constant.

$x=1/4$ is indeed the extremum on the intersection of curve plane $z=x-\sqrt{y}$ and plane $y=x$. The intersection, however, is a simple curve. It would be absurd to consider any partial derivative on a curve. In other words, we cannot even apply this principle, nor to prove it wrong.

Comment: On the wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Example:_Differentiation_with_direct_dependencies), why didn't they do the same to $f(x,y) = xy$ and apply the product rule?

Comment: I updated the answer. Just as mentioned in the answer above, the principle works for independent variables by which we can only obtain global extrema. But this problem is not the case.